# Longer Execution time for a query in toplink

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle11g, toplink

I Have a query that is assigned to this variable FILE_DETAILS in below piece of code, when this query is executed in SQLDeveloper/toad its getting executed faster, but when used in toplink or jdbc its taking a lot of execution time. What could be the possible reason for the longer execution time?

```
List resultSet = (List) toplinkMgr
                .readDataQuery(Constants.FILE_DETAILS,
                        arguments, values);
```

Comment: you can step by step debug it in eclipse to see what is hanging

Comment: include the query and execution code, are you fetching all of the rows in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

No DBA will help you unless you provide the query and the execution plan(s). Firrst of all compere execution plan for the query in Toad against the one executed from Toplink. See definition for the Oracle view V$SQL_PLAN, there you will find exec plan for currently running query.